# Returning Nested table from a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I would like to know how can I return a nested table from a `stored procedure` in oracle to consume in my `.net` client.

Basically I used the following format for creating nested table :

```
TYPE changes IS RECORD(
    col1 VARCHAR2(20),
    col2 VARCHAR2(20),
    col3 VARCHAR2(20)
);

TYPE collection is table of changes;
```

I'm populating this with values in stored procedure logic.

Now I want to return these values for my .net client. 
Can we try to dump nested tables values to cursor and return back. If yes then how ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if using ODP.net then know that you can [directly pass collection types](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E18754_01/featUDTs.htm) between a procedure and your UI. It is finicky, but it works.

If you want to simply dump a collection into a cursor to be returned, then look at the TABLE() function. In your example you could pass back a ref_cursor for the UI to traverse using something like (forgive any minor syntax glitches - I'm away from my database at the moment):

```
FUNCTION collection_to_cursor
return sys_refcursor
IS
   p_cursor  sys_refcursor;
   p_change changes;
BEGIN
Open p_cursor for (
   SELECT col1, col2, col3
   FROM   TABLE(p_change));
RETURN p_cursor;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ref cursor, something along the lines of

```
DECLARE
lt_collection collection := collection();
lrc_collection SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

lt_collection := f_populate_collection_somehow;

OPEN lrc_collection  
SELECT col1
      ,col2
      ,col3
FROM  TABLE(CAST(lt_collection AS collection));


END;
```

.NET can then retrieve the data from the ref cursor, I'm not sure of the details of how this is done.

There is some good further information on using ref cursors or associative arrays 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639646/oracle-stored-procedure-returning-ref-cursor-vs-associative-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

Please note, I am not conversant with .NET, so I am writing this literally to your question "how can I return a nested table from a stored procedure in oracle".
I am not sure about the "to consume in my .net client" portion, as I am not sure if a returned record type/table type can directly be used in .net code.

I did some research and what I learnt is that there is no direct support of record type in any oracle client interface. What people generally do is to create a wrapper procedure around the returned table type from function to convert it into a ref cursor and use the ref cursor in custom code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE changes AS OBJECT(
    col1 VARCHAR2(20),
    col2 VARCHAR2(20),
    col3 VARCHAR2(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE collection is table of changes;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test_pkg AS
  FUNCTION test_fn RETURN collection;
END test_pkg;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test_pkg
AS
  FUNCTION test_fn RETURN collection AS
  l_collection collection;
  BEGIN
    l_collection := collection();
    l_collection.EXTEND;
    l_collection(l_collection.LAST) := changes('Subhasis','Mukherjee','Male');
    RETURN l_collection;
  END test_fn;
END test_pkg;


SELECT * FROM table(test_pkg.test_fn)

col1              col2              col3
-----------       -------------     --------------
Subhasis          Mukherjee         Male
```